# ionic 3: How to create orderpay string to pass at alipay plug in from server side

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, ionic3, laravel-5.4, alipay

i have an existing ionic3 application i need to integrate alipay and we chat payment, i know there are plug for both but I need any reference of how to generate order string or payment object at server side **(Php laravel 5.4)** which can be pass to plugin's payment method.

I have go through alipay documentation but couldn't get proper guidance.

Any example code or any ref for the same would be appreciated.